# Django, Getting a value from a POST

Tags: python, django

I have in my template:

```
This is passed by {{form}}

    <form action="" method="POST">
        Inicio: <input type="text" id="start">
        <input type="submit" value="Sned" >
     {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
```

Then in the views.py

```
def test(request):

    if request.method != 'POST':
        context = {'form': 'by GET'}
        return render(request, 'test.html', context)
    else:

        if 'start' in request.POST:
            start = request.POST['start']
        else:
            start = False


    context = {'form': start}
    return render(request, 'test.html', context)
```

It seems that always return False

If I dont check the existance of the key I have this error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError
```

And the erropage says : "'start'" (single plus double quotes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id` is intended for javascript and css purposes. For variables that are important on server side, you should use `name` tag.

```
<input type="text" id="start" name="start">
```

Comment: Also did it but somehow it is still not marked as green and when I try to do it again it says Ill have to wait 10 mins

Comment: Try after 10 minutes, thanks for effort. Enjoy stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a name attribute in your input, so when you are getting the POST data it will be found.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    Inicio: <input type="text" id="start" name="start">
    <input type="submit" value="Sned" >
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Also I recommend you to do the following change in your view:

Replace

```
request.POST['start']
```

by:

```
request.POST.get('start')
```

So, if the field is not found, it will be reassigned whith a `None` value.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

add name

```
<input type="text" name="start" id="start">
```